# "Sliding window" over a list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am looking for a method that would allow me to create a *sliding window* on a list in Elixir, something like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
|> Enum.magic_function(2)
--> [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]
```

Kind of the `chunk_every` function, but with a shift of 1 each time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the third argument of [`Enum.chunk_every/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#chunk_every/4) to specify how many elements to skip after each chunk (you want `1` here) and the fourth one to tell it to discard the last chunk if it's smaller than the specified length.

```
iex(1)> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] |> Enum.chunk_every(2, 1, :discard)
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```